# wait fails in multithreaded application at 2.4 kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, pthreads, wait

I have an application that is multithreaded - one thread is responsible for collecting the dead children with wait(), anther thread spawns them with fork upon request.

I found out that on one platform with 2.4 kernel and LinuxThread wait always fails with ECHILD. I've found out that problem might be in non-POSIX compliant implementation of LinuxThreads on 2.4 kernel and the [following discussion](http://forum.soft32.com/linux2/pthreads-waitpid-ftopict11784.html) suggests that there is no way how this could be solved.

Still I'd like to be sure that nobody knows about any solution. Even patch for the kernel would be acceptable.

When I think about the application design I don't think it could be possible to do both fork() and wait() in a single thread (or only with enormous effort)

Comment: I don't think there's going to be any advice other than upgrading to a 2.6 kernel based distribution, with a POSIX-compliant threading library.

Comment: Mind showing some code ? Handling child process is deceptivly tricky, there's so many race conditions to think about.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this (obviously bogus) behavior is features of LinuxThreads implementation.

There really seems to be only two ways out - either switch to NPTL (requires kernel 2.6) or avoid such multi-threaded fork/wait model (this was my solution to the problem and tough it made the architecture a bit more complicated and complex it still was manageable to do in a single day)

Following example is the bare bone example of the bogus situation that fails on LinuxThreads.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

void * wait_for_child(void *arg)
{
    int s;
    pid_t ret;
    ret = wait(&s);
    if (ret == -1 && errno == ECHILD) perror("Bogus LinuxThreads encountered");
    return NULL;    
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) return 1;

    // child waits and then dies
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        sleep(3);
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_t wt;
    pthread_create(&wt, NULL, wait_for_child, NULL);
    pthread_join(wt, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting to think about kernel patches, then it's time to think about upgrades. 2.4 is very long in the tooth.

Comment: 2.4 has definitely been out for a long time, but it is still favored by some embedded projects where the kernel image size is an issue. See http://denx.de/wiki/Know/Linux24vs26 for a size comparison on PPC. Personally, I'd upgrade to 2.6.x because the improvements out weigh the size increase, but that's just me.

Comment: And this was also the case. For the given platform, only 2.4 series are supported by the supplier unfortunately. It is painful in many other aspects.